# В цикле while на c# не запускается Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, while

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CyclesDoWhile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Количество конфет в пачке
            int candies = 200;

            //Съедено конфет 
            int candiesEaten = 0;

            while(candiesEaten != 0)
            {
                candies--;
                candiesEaten++;
                Console.WriteLine("Конфет съедено. Осталось: " + candies + " Конфет съедено" + candiesEaten);
            }




            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код работал. Запускался, как положено. Сегодня решил повторить этот урок, все стер. Написал заново. Запускает пустое консольное окно. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У вас ошибка в условии цикла

```
//Количество конфет в пачке 
int candies = 200;

//Съедено конфет 
int candiesEaten = 0;

while(candiesEaten != 0)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Данный цикл ни разу не выполнится.

Я думаю вы имеете в виду

```
//Количество конфет в пачке 
int candies = 200;
//Съедено конфет 
int candiesEaten = 0;

while(candies != 0)
      ^^^^^^^
```